# Autocomplete from remote datasource doesn't give any suggestions

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete, jquery-ui-widget-factory

Autocomplete suggestion are narrowed based on the form. Thing is I am able to send filter(s) to the server; which also gives the correct output but it does not end up as suggestions (autocomplete) in the textarea.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Combined</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <style>
            .ui-autocomplete-category {
                font-weight: bold;
                padding: .2em .4em;
                margin: .8em 0 .2em;
                line-height: 1.5;
            }

            .ui-autocomplete {
                max-height: 100px;
                overflow-y: auto;
                /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
                overflow-x: auto;
            }

            .ui-autocomplete-loading {
                background: white url("../img/ui-anim.gif") right center no-repeat;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
                    _create: function () {
                        this._super();
                        this.widget().menu("option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)");
                    },
                    _renderMenu: function (ul, items) {
                        var that = this,
                                currentCategory = "";
                        $.each(items, function (index, item) {
                            var li;
                            if (item.event != currentCategory) {
                                ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.event + "</li>");
                                currentCategory = item.event;
                            }
                            /* li = that._renderItemData(ul, item);
                             if (item.event) {
                             li.attr("aria-label", item.event + " : " + item.label);
                             } */
                            $("<li></li>")
                                    .data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
                                    .append('<a href="javascript:;"><input type="checkbox"/>' + item.label + '</a>')
                                    .appendTo(ul);
                        });
                    }
                });

                $("#trade").catcomplete({
                    delay: 0,
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "tmp3.php",
                            data: {
                                trade: request.term,
                                trainingID: $('form[name=searchTraining] input[name=trainingID]').val(),
                                totalParticipants: $('form[name=searchTraining] input[name=totalParticipants]').val(),
                                male: $('form[name=searchTraining] input[name=male]').val(),
                                female: $('form[name=searchTraining] input[name=female]').val(),
                                district: $('form[name=searchTraining] input[name=district]').val(),
                                project: $('form[name=searchTraining] input[name=project]').val(),
                                fromDate: $('form[name=searchTraining] input[name=fromDate]').val(),
                                toDate: $('form[name=searchTraining] input[name=toDate]').val(),
                                rPerson: $('form[name=searchTraining] input[name=rPerson]').val()
                            },
                            success: response,
                            dataType: 'json',
                            minLength: 1
                        });
                    }
                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form name="searchTraining">
            <div class="ui-widget">
                <label for="search">Search: </label>
                <textarea class="tradeF" name='trade' id='trade' placeholder="Trade" autocomplete="on" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" size="21" ></textarea>
            </div>

            <input pattern="[0-9]+" placeholder="Training ID" name="trainingID" size="1" class="idF" type="text" title="TrainingID">
            <input autocomplete="on" pattern="[0-9]+" placeholder="Total" name="totalParticipants" size="3" type="text" class="totalF">
            <input autocomplete="on" pattern="[0-9]+" placeholder="Male" name="male" size="3" type="text" class="maleF">
            <input autocomplete="on" pattern="[0-9]+" placeholder="Female" name="female" size="3" type="text" class="femaleF">
            <input autocomplete="on" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" placeholder="District" name="district" size="3" type="text">
            <input autocomplete="on" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" placeholder="Project" name="project" size="3" type="text" value="kfw">
            From<input name="fromDate" size="3" type="text"><br />To<input name="toDate" size="3" type="text">
            <input autocomplete="on" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" placeholder="Venue" name="venue" size="3" type="text">
            <input autocomplete="on" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" placeholder="Resource Person" name="rPerson" size="3" type="text">
            <input type="hidden" name="defaulter" value="true" />
            <input type="hidden" name="questItem" value="" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

FYI: Server response is

```
[{event:'Commercial',label:'Adda Work'},
{event:'Commercial',label:'Alternative Dispute Resolution'},
{event:'Commercial',label:'Auto Electrician'},
{event:'Commercial',label:'Beautician'},
{event:'Staff',label:'Youth Activits Training'}]
```

I donot know where i am doing wrong But i had narrow it down to the $("#trade").catcomplete code block.

Answering to the twisty comment.
We don't needs a div wrapper for li. the following code will prove it. It basically the same except it doesn't uses remote data source.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Categories</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../res/jquery/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
        <style>
            .ui-autocomplete-category {
                font-weight: bold;
                padding: .2em .4em;
                margin: .8em 0 .2em;
                line-height: 1.5;
            }

            .ui-autocomplete {
                max-height: 600px;
                overflow-y: auto;
                /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
                overflow-x: auto;
            }

            .ui-autocomplete-loading {
                background: white url("../img/ui-anim.gif") right center no-repeat;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="../../res/jquery/jquery1.x/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="../../res/jquery/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
                    _create: function () {
                        this._super();
                        this.widget().menu("option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)");
                    },
                    _renderMenu: function (ul, items) {
                        var that = this,
                                currentCategory = "";
                        $.each(items, function (index, item) {
                            var li;
                            if (item.event != currentCategory) {
                                ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.event + "</li>");
                                currentCategory = item.event;
                            }
                            $("<li></li>")
                                    .data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
                                    .append('<a href="javascript:;"><input type="checkbox"/>' + item.label + '</a>')
                                    .appendTo(ul);
                        });
                    }
                });

                var data = [{event: 'Community', label: 'Agriculture Ex Worker (AEW)'},
                    {event: 'Community', label: 'BMT Trainings for CRPs'},
                    {event: 'Community', label: 'Carpentry'},
                    {event: 'Community', label: 'Fruits & Forest Nursery (Production & Marketting)'},
                    {event: 'Community', label: 'Heavy Machinery Excavator'},
                    {event: 'Community', label: 'Masonry'},
                    {event: 'Community', label: 'Mobile Repairing'},
                    {event: 'Community', label: 'Motor Cycle Repairing'},
                    {event: 'Community', label: 'Operation & Maintenance'},
                    {event: 'Community', label: 'Solar Panel Installation'},
                    {event: 'Community', label: 'Tailoring & Embroidery'},
                    {event: 'Staff', label: 'Engineers Training'},
                    {event: 'Staff', label: 'Engineers Training (Solar Panal)'},
                    {event: 'Staff', label: 'FATA Engineers Meeting'},
                    {event: 'Staff', label: 'FATA Projects Review Meeting'},
                    {event: 'Staff', label: 'Staff Orientation'}];

                $("#trade").catcomplete({
                 delay: 0,
                 source: data
                 });

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form name="searchTraining">
            <div class="ui-widget">
                <label for="search">Search: </label>
                <textarea class="tradeF" name='trade' id='trade' placeholder="Trade" autocomplete="on" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" size="21" ></textarea>
            </div>

            <input pattern="[0-9]+" placeholder="Training ID" name="trainingID" size="1" class="idF" type="text" title="TrainingID">
            <input autocomplete="on" pattern="[0-9]+" placeholder="Total" name="totalParticipants" size="3" type="text" class="totalF">
            <input autocomplete="on" pattern="[0-9]+" placeholder="Male" name="male" size="3" type="text" class="maleF">
            <input autocomplete="on" pattern="[0-9]+" placeholder="Female" name="female" size="3" type="text" class="femaleF">
            <input autocomplete="on" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" placeholder="District" name="district" size="3" type="text">
            <input autocomplete="on" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" placeholder="Project" name="project" size="3" type="text" value="kfw">
            From<input name="fromDate" size="3" type="text"><br />To<input name="toDate" size="3" type="text">
            <input autocomplete="on" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" placeholder="Venue" name="venue" size="3" type="text">
            <input autocomplete="on" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" placeholder="Resource Person" name="rPerson" size="3" type="text">
            <input type="hidden" name="defaulter" value="true" />
            <input type="hidden" name="questItem" value="" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

the above code works i.e. autocomplete suggestion do show up. but it is basically useless for me because the source of the autocomplete is static where as mine requirement is it to be generated dynamically.

As far as the what javascript code will pop up is later issue (which code is not included above).

Thanks for the comments anyway.

Comment: autocomplete needs to be stored in a local array that the autocomplete function can search

Comment: When rendering your items, I am pretty sure you want to add a `<div>` wrapper around your items, inside each `<li>`.

Comment: Also, think you will have some issues since you have checkboxes within your results. Not sure which click event will bubble up, to the selection or the checkbox.

Comment: We don't needs a div wrapper for li. the following code will prove it. It basically the same except it doesn't uses remote data source.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions. As you have not provided any sample data, it's difficult to test or provide an example answer.

```js
$(function() {
  $.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _create: function() {
      this._super();
      this.widget().menu("option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)");
    },
    _renderMenu: function(ul, items) {
      var that = this,
        currentCategory = "";
      $.each(items, function(index, item) {
        var li;
        if (item.event != currentCategory) {
          ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.event + "</li>");
          currentCategory = item.event;
        }
        li = $("<li></li>")
          .data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
          .append('<div><a href="javascript:;"><input type="checkbox"/>' + item.label + '</a></div>')
          .appendTo(ul);
      });
    }
  });

  $("#trade").catcomplete({
    delay: 0,
    source: function(request, response) {
      var myForm = $("form[name='searchTraining']");
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "tmp3.php",
        data: {
          trade: request.term,
          trainingID: $('[name=trainingID]', myForm).val(),
          totalParticipants: $('[name=totalParticipants]', myForm).val(),
          male: $('[name=male]', myForm).val(),
          female: $('[name=female]', myForm).val(),
          district: $('[name=district]', myForm).val(),
          project: $('[name=project]', myForm).val(),
          fromDate: $('[name=fromDate]', myForm).val(),
          toDate: $('[name=toDate]', myForm).val(),
          rPerson: $('[name=rPerson]', myForm).val()
        },
        success: response,
        dataType: 'json',
        minLength: 1
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-autocomplete-category {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: .2em .4em;
  margin: .8em 0 .2em;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.ui-autocomplete {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.ui-autocomplete-loading {
  background: white url("../img/ui-anim.gif") right center no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form name="searchTraining">
  <div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="search">Search: </label>
    <textarea class="tradeF" name='trade' id='trade' placeholder="Trade" autocomplete="on" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" size="21"></textarea>
  </div>
  <input pattern="[0-9]+" placeholder="Training ID" name="trainingID" size="1" class="idF" type="text" title="TrainingID">
  <input autocomplete="on" pattern="[0-9]+" placeholder="Total" name="totalParticipants" size="3" type="text" class="totalF">
  <input autocomplete="on" pattern="[0-9]+" placeholder="Male" name="male" size="3" type="text" class="maleF">
  <input autocomplete="on" pattern="[0-9]+" placeholder="Female" name="female" size="3" type="text" class="femaleF">
  <input autocomplete="on" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" placeholder="District" name="district" size="3" type="text">
  <input autocomplete="on" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" placeholder="Project" name="project" size="3" type="text" value="kfw"> From
  <input name="fromDate" size="3" type="text"><br />To<input name="toDate" size="3" type="text">
  <input autocomplete="on" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" placeholder="Venue" name="venue" size="3" type="text">
  <input autocomplete="on" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" placeholder="Resource Person" name="rPerson" size="3" type="text">
  <input type="hidden" name="defaulter" value="true" />
  <input type="hidden" name="questItem" value="" />
</form>
```

Comment: Sir, first thanks for d answer.

Did the code that you provide; runs, because it gives an error when i enter character in the textarea.
As far as sample data is concern any character will do for instance type 'a' in textarea .It does not concern what is typed; just as long as it will some suggestions in textarea.
Server side should just need to echo an json array e.g.

    <?php
    
    echo "[" .
     "{ event: 'Community', label: 'Agriculture Ex (AEW)'}" .
     ",{ event: 'Staff', label: 'FATA Projects'}" .
     ",{ event: 'Staff', label: 'Staff Orientation'}]";
    ?>

Comment: OK yours code is correct except for the last rPerson where you missed a square bracket and myForm should be searchTraining. But nevertheless I had replace my code with yours and it also didn't give suggestions or autocomplete.

Comment: @Adeel what do you see in console? What response do you see under Network section?

Comment: If I type Mo; under console I got noting. i.e. no errors whereas under 
 network section i got this; [{event:'Community',label:'Mobile Repairing'}, 
   {event:'Community',label:'Motor Cycle Repairing'}]

Comment: Ok. So ajax is running and returning results. Would consider adding some console.log() parts in your each.

Comment: I had added console.log('event:' + item.event + ', label:' + item.label); but didn't get any thing on console. Can you sir kindly execute it on your system. I believe you would also get nothing. I believe it some very small and technical mistake, which sadly I can't figure out. Previously I added alert in each loop but also got nothing. BTW $.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, block is correct (because it worked correctly when working with static data).

Comment: @Adeel I have no way to *execute it on my system* as you suggest since I do not have access to the same PHP scripts as you. I cannot replicate the AJAX query. When you said you "didn't get anything on console," was it blank or was the result like `event:, label:`?

Comment: Because of limit on charecters in comment I will divide my comment in 3

@Twisty Sir, as I said before just create any json array (it does matter what actual data goes into the array a long as its an array and it had 2 fields i.e. event and label. I had given serveral times sample of that json array in previous comments. Even just echoing array in php file is enough. e.g. 
<?php echo "[{event:'Community',label:'Agriculture Ex Worker (AEW)'},{ event: 'Community', label: 'BMT Trainings for CRPs'}]"; ?>

Comment: As long as ajax is concern does create any ajax query, just calling the server side script is enough; because I don’t have any error on my server side nor I had any need of server side filtering because server side is correct as you even said yourself “So ajax is running and returning results”. I need help on client side i.e. correct my autocomplete. So I again request you to just use this form as it is and on server side or php file just echo an array. Usually it would be shown a suggestions or autocomplete but here because of some unknown jquery cryptic problem it doesn’t. So can you help me

Comment: Btw: I had search on net and one person said one solution to remove all spaces in json array i.e. in between json variable name and colon and in between colon and variable value. Sadly I had even done that and had even created json array myself instead of using php function json_encode but still no autocomplete. See it this kind of cryptic error that I am not understanding and am stuck.

My console is blank which if you execute on yours will also be :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was as I suspected minor and cryptic coding of JavaScript. When I created the Json array in php I used quote instead of double quote. i.e.

```
"{'event':'Community','label':'Agriculture'}"
```

instead i should had used

```
'{"event":"Community","label":"Agriculture"}'
```

when i reverse quote with double quote it worked like a charm.
btw: @twisty thanks for helping me along the way.